# How to get details of a task from task_id in flutter download manager

Tags: android, flutter

I want to perform certain work after the download has been successfully completed.
I am using flutterDownloader for enqueue download on android.

```
FlutterDownloader.registerCallback(DummyClass.callback);
final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(

          url: 'url-to-download',
          savedDir: saveDir,
          fileName: file_name,
          showNotification:
              false,
          openFileFromNotification:
              false,
        );
```

I get taskid, status and progress in callback function. But I do not get any details about task such as file_name.
Based on file_name and status I need to perform another work.

How to get file_name from taskId?

I tried loadTasks and loadTasksWithRawQuery. Both are not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can get task detail from `FlutterDownloader.loadTasks();`

Please check below code :

```
Future task() async {
    List<DownloadTask>? getTasks = await FlutterDownloader.loadTasks();
    getTasks?.forEach((_task) {
      DownloadMovieVo downloadMovieVo = DownloadMovieVo();
      downloadMovieVo.status = _task.status;
      downloadMovieVo.progress = _task.progress;
      downloadMovieVo.taskId = _task.taskId;
      downloadMovieVo.fileName = _task.filename;
      downloadMovieVo.savedDirectory = _task.savedDir;
      _downloadMovie.add(downloadMovieVo);
      refresh();
    });
  }
```

Comment: it gives `'_initialized': plugin flutter_downloader is not initialized` even though i initialized it in main class.